# How does server works with limited number of ports?

Tags: http

As far as I know, a (single generic) webserver uses ports (like any other tcp/upd application) to identify users/process. Since, a port is a 16-bit unsigned integer, thus ranging from 0 to 65535. How does server act when it reaches its limit?

**High level sample**

1. The server1 answering by 8080! The **client1** conect to server1 (now they are connected by random ports: (but unique) server1:**5123** <--> client1:6123)
2. Another **client2** connect to the server1 ( server1:**5124** <--> client2:7123 )

So, the thing is: *Is the server limited by 65535 (in pratical less than that) for a given instance?*

Answer (score 2):

In the simplest case a webserver consumes only one TCP port (conventionally port 80) on the server system.  All of the connections to the webserver are handled through that single port.  The other 65534 ports remain available for other uses.

This works because a TCP connection is identified not just by the port number on the server, but by the combination of **(server IP, server TCP port, client IP, client TCP port)**.  So the server can have a huge number of concurrent TCP connections all on its port 80, using the other three items to identify which connection the traffic belongs to.  If the server only has a single IP address, and therefore the **(server IP, server port)** portions are identical on all connections to the webserver, the individual connections are still distinguishable by the **(client IP, client port)** portions of the combination.

If you run the `netstat -a` command on a busy Unix webserver you'll see this in action.  That command will show a bunch of connections on the server's port 80, but all with different client IPs and/or ports.  It'll also show that the system is still listening for new connections on port 80, at the same time as it is handling all of the existing connections on that port.

The total number of connections to the webserver might be limited by some other constraint (perhaps memory usage, perhaps some arbitrary limit in the webserver itself or in the OS kernel) or by some external constraint (perhaps connection table size in external firewalls or gateways) but it's not limited by the 16-bit TCP port range.

Also note that TCP ports are completely separate from UDP ports, so using TCP port 80 for a webserver does not prevent UDP port 80 from being used for some other purpose.  And vice versa.